# Can I create an array with indirect?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some weekly stock return data that looks like this:
[image]

I've hidden a lot of rows there, obviously. But basically there are 200ish different stocks and their weekly returns over the course of 10 years. They are paired with a return in column E for the same period for the S&P 500. I want to calculate betas with these `Covariance(Stock, S&P 500)/Variance(S&P 500)`. I'm struggling just to create the Covariance portion right now:

Column A in my new sheet is a unique list of all the ticker symbols and my formula is as follows:

```
=COVARIANCE.P(INDIRECT("'Weekly Data'!D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!F:F,0)&":'Weekly Data'!D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!G:G,0)),INDIRECT("'Weekly Data'!E$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!F:F,0)&":'Weekly Data'!E$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!G:G,0)))
```

Getting a #REF error.

Comment: in your formula bar, highlight sub-functions within your big formula then push F9. this will give you the value that the function beneath the cursor will compute. i bet one of those yields a #REF! error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation

```
"'Weekly Data'!D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!F:F,0)&":'Weekly Data'!D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!G:G,0)
```

leads to the wrong string representation of a cell range address.

It leads to `'Weekly Data'!D$2:'Weekly Data'!D$528` in case of ORCL. But in `Excel` it would must be `'Weekly Data'!D$2:D$528`. Note, the sheet name only once.

So correct formula would be

```
=COVARIANCE.P(INDIRECT("'Weekly Data'!D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!F:F,0)&":D$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!G:G,0)),INDIRECT("'Weekly Data'!E$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!F:F,0)&":E$"&MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!G:G,0)))
```

But as often `INDIRECT` could be replaced by `INDEX`. This is the better approach because of the volatile behavior of `INDIRECT`, which gets recalculated on each change in sheet and not only on change of the cells in function parameters.

The `INDEX` formula would be:

```
=COVARIANCE.P(INDEX('Weekly Data'!$D:$D,MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!$F:$F,0)):INDEX('Weekly Data'!$D:$D,MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!$G:$G,0)),INDEX('Weekly Data'!$E:$E,MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!$F:$F,0)):INDEX('Weekly Data'!$E:$E,MATCH(A2,'Weekly Data'!$G:$G,0)))
```